# DeployedBytecode doesn't match

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, verification, truffle

so I encountered a weird issue with deploying bytecodes via a deployer contract. On 1 of 5 deployed contracts via the same compilation round & deployment flow I ended having a different deployedBytecode (but same bytecode) as with my original truffle compiled source. Therefore I can't get it verified. The issue seems that the address of the deployer contract is part of the deployedBytecode (while on my local file it is the null address). The issue is also only for 1 contract, while all 5 contracts share the same code (especially around the deployer address mentioned inside the contract.

So here i.e. is the deployer contract (+ verified source code):
https://polygonscan.com/address/0xd54716865c58d11e7c39c3cf634d9e919c0c6cce#code

I deployed my contract (SignerVaultV1.sol) via that tx:
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x4d6e3a002b448e675ba6a2374737d4eaf0e18b163a57a66c09109ba332c8c5e3

The bytecode of it is exactly the same as on my local file, but if the deployedBytecodes are compared, 3 changes can be seen: [Diff between online vs offline deployedBytecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNNqO.png) (I can't post pics yet^^)

The difference in it is the address of the deployer contract (d54716865c58d11e7c39c3cf634d9e919c0c6cce). But like I said, the deployerContract delivered multiple contracts, all are correct, only this one is having that issue and I cant figure it out why.

I personally would like to get that contract verified without having to redeploy it (and maybe rund into the same issue...) I tried already to alter the source code to match the online deployedBytecode, but it seems also a harsh idea :D

Answer (score 0):

Well after testing different ways, I dont honestly why, but sending a verification request via hardhat got it working... I couldn't manually verify or via truffle, but hardhat seems to know the magic for the last contract :)